# Why do I have to specify the python version when creating a new conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, virtual-environment

I do `conda create --name env` then `conda activate env`.

My prompt now has `(env)` at the beginning of it. Then I try running `python` at the prompt and it returns

```
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

The [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) explicitly states

> This environment uses the same version of Python that you are currently using because you did not specify a version.

However, if I do `conda create --name env python=3.8`, my environment correctly runs python 3.8. It seems like if I don't specify a version, my environment is completely empty (which it is when I look in the directory). But the documentation says that it should have the version of python from the base. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using an anaconda prompt in Windows 10.

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, this is just how conda works. The documentation is probably a little bit unclear... what it means is that if you specify a package that depends on Python (but is not itself Python), say, NumPy, then the Python version used to satisfy the dependency will be the same as the current environment.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce on my machine. When creating an empty environment and activating it, `python` still points to `C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\python.exe`. Which version of conda are you using? Can you add the output of `echo %PATH%` before and after activating `env` to your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that bit of documentation is outdated and is a hold-over from pre-v4.4, when the recommended practice was to put the **base** env's `bin/` directory on `PATH`. In Conda v4.4+, the **base** env is no longer accessible by default when another env is activated.

To have Python in an env, one must explicitly request it to be installed, e.g.,

```
conda create --name env python
```

Note, one doesn't have to specify a version.

In the end, this should be seen as an advantage, since it allows users to create non-Python envs and keeps the **base** env isolated.