# Why do my anaconda new environments use homebrew for python path?

Tags: python, anaconda, ipython, pythonpath, pythoninterpreter

I tried creating different conda environments, and all of them except base have this same issue to some degree: some python versions have the correct anaconda path, but some lead to the homebrew pythons.

For example,

`(base) ~ % which python3`

`~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3`

`(base) ~ % which python`

`~/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`

`(base) ~ % which ipython`

`~/opt/anaconda3/bin/ipython`

---

after `conda activate env1`:

`(env1) ~ % which python3`

`~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python3`

`(env1) ~ % which python3`

`~/opt/anaconda3/envs/ml/bin/python`

`(env1) ~ % which ipython`

`/opt/homebrew/bin/ipython` (notice the absence of `~/`)

---

after `conda activate env2`:

`(env2) ~ % which python`

`/usr/bin/python`

`(env2) ~ % which python3`

`/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`

`(env2)~ % which ipython`

`/opt/homebrew/bin/ipython`

I would really appreciate it if you could let me know why this would happen, and how I could change these python paths to the anaconda version! My work depends on this, and I would especially love to get the `ipython` versions to work with anaconda. Thank you!

Comment: How are you creating these environments? Environments are empty by default (not even Python). Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60288583/570918

Comment: If you could add the output of `conda env list` as well as answer @merv comment above that would help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Python installed via `homebrew` and `conda` are not friends, and they can conflict with each other. I recently encountered a situation where I set up an environment using `conda` and ran `serverless local` commands in this environment. It turned out that `serverless local` picked up Python form `brew` instead of `conda`. After some troubleshooting, I found out that overriding the `$PATH` variable just before a `serverless` command can help. For instance turning the below npm script:

```
"start": "cross-env DEBUG=true  sls offline --aws-profile ayata start --host 0.0.0.0 --lambdaPort 3002 --verbose"
```

to

```
"start": "export PATH=\"$CONDA_PREFIX/bin:$PATH\" &&  cross-env DEBUG=true  sls offline --aws-profile ayata start --host 0.0.0.0 --lambdaPort 3002 --verbose"
```

I was working in a Linux only environment and had no worries about compatibility.

<sub>**Note**: This will not work on Windows systems</sub>